# Can I use Node Reference Field as a Text Field if there are no references?

Tags: nodes, entities, ajax, 7

I'm creating a content type Event. I want to reference the node of another content type Venue, so the user will be able to click to the venue node from the event.

To reference the venue on the Event creation page, ideally it would be a text field with autocomplete showing a list of possible venue nodes.

Now if the venue node hasn't been created yet, can Drupal allow the Event to be created using the entered text as display (i.e plain text)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) module.

> Node Reference Create is an enhancement to the nodereference autocomplete widget that allows users to reference non-existent nodes.
>
> When no matching node is selected, the new nodes are automatically created allowing for a seamless and intuitive user experience that is similar to free tagging.

Comment: Ideally I just want it displayed as plain text. I don't want a new node to be created if it is not complete.

Comment: This is not possible using a node reference field, regardless of the widget you use to enter field values. The reference is saved using the primary key of the node table, which is an integer. You would have to write your own field module.

Comment: Would you be available for paid help?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutly possible

- on drupal 6, the module "Text or Nodereference" does exactly that (use the dev version) http://drupal.org/project/text_noderef.
- on drupal 7, follow the instructions of this page : http://drupal.org/node/1422672